# I am using the Peoplesoft test framework writing data captured via variables to a file

Tags: peoplesoft

I am using the Peoplesoft test framework. on creating a script I captured several values using variable now I want to write these values to a file. Tried to do several searches and no luck at all on this subject. Also once I have written these to a file I want to the compare them agains values in another script......any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Could you update a column in a table with the value from script 1, update a different column with the value from script 2 and then compare the columns?

Would this satisfy your requirement?